# Getting "Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported" when submitting query

Tags: soql, query, java, selectlist

I'm using Java to query SF, using the aPI version 33.0.  I'm trying to submit the following query

```
SELECT Id, EODBID__c from Account where Id in (Select AccountId from Opportunity where RecordTypeId in (select Id from RecordType where Name = 'My Record Type'))
```

but its returning the error

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:120
```

Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

Is there another way I can write the above to avoid this error?  I would prefer to submit a single query only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest more than once, as the error says, but in this case, you can use the relationship field instead:

```
SELECT Id, EODBID__c 
from Account 
where Id in 
  (Select AccountId 
   from Opportunity 
   where RecordType.Name = 'My Record Type')
```